# How to install JRE on FreeBSD 8?

Tags: freebsd, java

I'm newbie on FreeBSD.
How to install JRE on FreeBSD 8.x?

Comment: If you know any other way instead of pkg_add, please let me know.

Comment: Similar: [*Install Java 9, 10, 11, or 12 on FreeBSD 11.1*](https://serverfault.com/q/942101/142214)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (yet).

If you look at http://www.FreeBSDFoundation.org/downloads/java.shtml you'll see that the FreeBSD Foundation has packages for FreeBSD 6 and 7, but not for 8.

There may be another way, or someone else may even have created packages, but if they have, I don't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 11, & 12 available

Work has recently resumed to keep up-to-date the [Ports & Packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports) tree on FreeBSD for the latest and greatest Java versions.

These versions are based on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project (a consortium of Oracle, IBM, Apple, and others).

- OpenJDK 8 ([JDK](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk8), [JRE](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk8-jre))
- [OpenJDK 11](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk11)
- [OpenJDK 12](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/java/openjdk12)

To install:

```
sudo pkg install openjdk12
```

You will find OpenJDK installed in `/usr/local/openjdk12/`.

You may want to set some environment variables to point to your OpenJDK installation. For example, in my `.zshrc` configuration file for [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell), I add this line:

```
path+=/usr/local/openjdk12/bin
```

Note that there is **no longer any JRE** for later versions of Java. With [Applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) and [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) being phased out, there is no longer a need for end-users to install a Java runtime. Desktop and console apps are expected to be built with a Java runtime bundled inside. The [Java Platform Module System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) and related tools such as [jlink](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) make this easier than ever, with a smaller runtime that includes only the libraries actually used by your particular app. For more info and links, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/642706) on sister site Stack Overflow.

In the future, you may also find releases of OpenJDK for FreeBSD on the [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) web site. AdoptOpenJDK is a cooperative effort of some folks in the Java community to regularly publish binary builds of OpenJDK.

Be aware of the [new Java release cadence](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/update-and-faq-on-the-java-se-release-cadence). Java 8 and Java 11 are the current [Long-term support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) releases.

If you want to follow the progress on porting Java to FreeBSD, or perhaps assist, see [this mailing list](https://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-java).