# Install Java 9, 10, 11, or 12 on FreeBSD 11.1

Tags: java, freebsd, bsd, freebsd-ports

When I look to my up-to-date [Ports collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports):

```bash
cd /usr/ports/java && ls -d openjdk*
```

… I see only versions 6, 7, and 8 of Java in the OpenJDK releases:

> openjdk6   openjdk6-jre    openjdk7    openjdk7-jre    openjdk8    openjdk8-jre

➥ How does one **obtain and install an open-source versions of the [Java platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform))** later than 8? That would be versions [9, 10, 11, or 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) of Java? Preferably at least 11, that being the [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) (long-term support) release.

The [*FreeBSD Java® Project*](https://www.freebsd.org/java/) page is suspiciously quiet about anything since Java 8.

I know there are various sources for Java such as:

- [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com)
- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net)
- [OpenJ9](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/) by Eclipse
- IBM
- Oracle
- Red Hat
- [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/)

But none of these offer a [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution)-specific release, not that I could find.

## Use Java for Linux?

Some of those sources do offer Linux releases. Does Java for Linux run on a FreeBSD machine using the [*Linux® Binary Compatibility*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu.html) feature?

Is that the usual way to run Java on FreeBSD nowadays?

## Previous Questions on this topic

My question here is an updated version of questions such as these listed below. (Much has changed in the Java world since these were posted!)

- [*How to install JRE on FreeBSD 8?*](https://serverfault.com/q/196471/142214)
- [*java for freebsd*](https://serverfault.com/q/237646/142214)
- [*installing java on freeBSD*](https://serverfault.com/q/387919/142214)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Java 11 & 12

OpenJDK 11 and 12 can now be found in the Ports tree. See:

- [java/openjdk11](https://www.freshports.org/java/openjdk11/)
- [java/openjdk12](https://www.freshports.org/java/openjdk12/)

[An effort is underway](https://docs.freebsd.org/cgi/getmsg.cgi?fetch=153025+0+archive/2019/freebsd-java/20190317.freebsd-java) to see future versions of OpenJDK for FreeBSD regularly made available alongside the other OSes such as macOS, Linux, AIX, etc.

## Prior versions

During the time of Java 9 & 10 the BSD work was [ongoing](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222568). While 9 & 10 were skipped, 11 & 12 are available now. Reminder: [Java SE 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11) is the [Long-Term Support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version according to the new 6-month release cadence adopted by Oracle and the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

Java 8 was released for BSD, and is available in the Ports tree.

As for running Oracle (Linux) Java - it is possible, but this JRE is unstable. For instance, installing MATLAB using it crashes the installer randomly during the process. However, your mileage may wary.